# HTML Video Not Loading

Tags: javascript, html, loading

I have just created my new web page and have set up hosting for it. The web page contains a video which should play. However the video just constantly loads and doesn't do anything.

Is this because the video is having to download from the web server?

Here is the code:

```
<video id="video" width="600" height="400" controls autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="fire.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The code works locally with no issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the video on the server also, or just your HTML?

Comment: Is the fire.mp4 file in the same folder as the .html page?

Comment: Either your browser doesn't support mp4 (don't know how likely that is) or your source is misspelled? Check your [web dev network tab](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: My browser is chrome. The HTML is in the same file as the video!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting video in the source directory, you maybe wanna use:

`html
<video id="video" width="600" height="400" controls autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="/fire.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>`

Yes I added a backslash before fire.mp4 in the source of the source tag, as / is used to get content from root directory.
This of course only works if you have "fire.mp4" in the same directory as your html file.
If it is in a different directory just do this maybe:

`html
<video id="video" width="600" height="400" controls autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="/path/to/dir/fire.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>`

Comment: What browser and version are you using? Older browser or some specific might not be able to use the html video tag, you may check over at W3Schools - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: <video width="600" height="400" controls autoplay>
<source src="fire.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Of chrome that is

Comment: The thing is before I hosted the website online, it was working perfectly locally.

Comment: What are you hosting with, it is the thing that might causes it? Like hosting software etc. etc. Even tho I don't know a thing about that.

Comment: Microsoft Azure